# Difference between hcitool scan and inq

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, hci

Looking at the hcitool command on linux, what is the technical difference between

```
hcitool scan
```

and

```
hcitool inq
```

I understand in bluetooth the remote devices respond to an inquiry from the local device (Inquiry scan mode). What is a "scan" from the local device though, and how does it differ from an inquiry?

Answer (score 5):

First off - sorry this is a late answer, I am a new member here.

`hcitool scan` scans for any device and returns the name and the MAC address.

`hcitool inq` inquires about a device, and receives the MAC address, clock offset and class. The **clock offset** can be ignored as it's just a low-level value. Whereas the **class** tells you what type of device you are talking too, whether it be a bluetooth headset, phone or speakers etc.

However, if you are trying to scan for a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), none of the above commands will work. You can use the following command to do so:

`hcitool lescan`

And if you wish to connect to a BLE energy device, use:

`hcitool lecc 00:11:22:33:44:55`

OR `gatttool` works with any Bluetooth device:

`sudo gatttool -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 –I`

With `gatttool`, you can read, write and arithmetic with the device.

**Update:**

If you want to break it down to the lower level, view [this code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/tools/hcitool.c?id=7e018c6e02e39faa3b12f144390be4942bd316e6).

Line **435** for `inq`.

Line **521** for `scan`.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Davies! ... My question was not clear, apologies, but what I was actually hoping to find out was at a "lower-level" what is the fundamental difference between the two in terms of the bluetooth protocol. Are they both using bluetooth inquiry mode? Are both "sets" of data (from the hcitool scan and hcitool inq recieved as responces from an inquiry scan? ... does that make sense?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the lower level code for you to look at @ChrisVollo

Comment: No problem, don't forget to tick for the right answer :) @ChrisVollo

Comment: why hcitool scan is different then hcitool lescan, I dont' see any difference

Comment: hcitool lescan is BT Low Energy (BLE), 
hcitool scan is BT Classic.
Both are at least partially very different

Answer (score 0):

dev  - identify LOCAL , physically connected bluetooth devices

scan - scanning for nearby (remote) bluetooth devices , hence NOT LOCAL 
       returns address and name

inq  - returns address plus more